# DeviceMotionEvent and DeviceOrientationEvent are missing on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, sensors

The following is the user-agent of my Samsung Galaxy Tab

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; SM-T580 Build/M1AJQ; wv)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   **Chrome/76.0.3809.89** Safari/537.36

Note that as of today (Aug 8 2019) this is the latest version of chrome. For a reference here is my Pixel 3 user-agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel 3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) **Chrome/76.0.3809.89** Mobile Safari/537.36

Both have the same chrome version.

When inspecting the `window.DeviceOrientationEvent` on the tablet I get `undefined` and on the pixel phone `ƒ DeviceOrientationEvent() { [native code] }`.

This fact causes my orientation listeners to fail on the tablet.

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

How can that be, if the chrome versions are the same?
Is there a Samsung "disabling mechanism" as default behavior, or maybe a bug?

What are your speculations?

Comment: I have the same problem on my Galaxy Tab A - I can't seem to get deviceorientation and devicemotion in JavaScript.

Comment: Some devices, like the Galaxy Tab, don't have a gyroscope hardware and rely on the accelerometer instead. Therefore, no events are available.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it could be interesting to know why this is happening.
I have the same problem on my smartphone Galaxy S10.
The user agent is this one :

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G973F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Chrome/80.0.3987.119** Mobile Safari/537.36

When I see the browser compatibility table [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/deviceorientation_event#Browser_compatibility) I can't understand why my phone won't manage to fire this event.

**What can help here** (you may already have tried this) is to replace this event by the `orientationchange` event that allows you to keep an eye on orientation of the device as well.

You have a short doc [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event)!

And I made an example for my tests and I am happy to share, here you are :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Orientation - Screen Mode</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
    <span id="mode" />
    <script>
    (function() {
        var mode = document.getElementById('mode');
        function modeFrom(orientationAngle) {
            return orientationAngle !== 0? 'landscape': 'portrait';
        }
        function setInfosFrom(o, value) {
            value = 'Non compatible browser!';
            if (o !== undefined) {
                value = modeFrom(o) + " (angle " + o + "&deg;)";
            }
            mode.innerHTML = value;
        }
        function setInfos() {
            setInfosFrom(window.orientation);
        }
        setInfos();
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setInfos, false);
    }());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you or some other readers! :)

Have a good day!